# A simple android application for pdf reading only

Tags: android, pdf

i am very new to android development..........i have searched the stack overflow archives but nothing seem to work for me....
i just need an application to read PDFs files in android on button click....
-just PDFs read (no writing or converting or anything)

please if someone can guide me in the right direction and which library to get.......
used itext but its not working.......application crashing on

```
Document document = new Document();
```

any help would be appreciated.....thank you

Comment: use google docs to display the pdf

Answer (score 0):

you can read pdf files using `WebView` like

```
mWebView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+ webUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use an implicit intent, put the PDF file path in an URL and launch it with the intent with ACTION_VIEW, it will launch with the default PDF application.